# Symmetry of i.i.d. continuous r.v.s problem

Tags: probability, random-variables

I have the following problem:

> Athletes compete one at a time at the high jump. Let $X_j$ be how high the $j^{th}$ jumper jumped, with $X_1, X_2, \dots$ i.i.d. with a continuous distribution. We say that the $j^{th}$ jumper sets a record if $X_j$ is greater than all of $X_{j - 1}, \dots, X_1$.
>
> 1. Is the event "the 110th jumper sets a record" independent of the event "the 111th jumper sets a record"?

The solution provided is as follows:

> 1. Let $I_j$ be the indicator r.v. for the $j$th jumper setting a record. By symmetry, $P(I_j = 1) = 1/j$. So, $P(I_{110} = 1, I_{111} = 1) = \dfrac{109!}{111!} = \dfrac{1}{110 \times 111} = P(I_{110} = 1)P(I_{111} = 1)$. The answer is yes.

Now, I understand that two events $A$ and $B$ are independent if

$$P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$$

But what I'm having difficulty understanding is how the author immediately makes the conclusion that

$$P(I_{110} = 1, I_{111} = 1) = \dfrac{109!}{111!}$$

The fact that

$$P(I_{110} = 1, I_{111} = 1) = \dfrac{1}{110 \times 111} = P(I_{110} = 1)P(I_{111} = 1),$$

if we begin by assuming that $I_{110}$ and $I_{111}$ are independent, is clear to me. But the point of the problem is that we can't assume this and must deduce it.

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number of possibility to sort $111$ numbers is $111!$.

To have $I_{110}=1, I_{111}=1$, it means $X_{111}$ is the largest number followed by $X_{110}$. There is no restriction on the first $109$ numbers besides that they must be smaller than the last two numbers.  There are $109!$ permutations.

Hence $P(I_{110}=1, I_{111}=1)=\frac{109!}{111!}$

By similar reasoning
$P(I_{110}=1)=\frac{109!}{110!}$ and $P(I_{111}=1)=\frac{110!}{111!}$.

Comment: Why is $P(I_{110}=1)=\frac{109!}{110!}$ instead of $P(I_{110}=1)=\frac{110!}{111!}$? Why are we not accounting for $I_{111}$ in this case?

Comment: For $I_{110}=1$, we just need $X_{110}$ to be larger than all previous values, the next value that appear doesn't influence it.

Answer (score 1):

$$
P(I_{110}=1,I_{111}=1)=\frac{109!}{111!}
$$

There are 111! different orderings of that the $X_i$ can be in.  The only way both $I_{110}$ can be 1 and $I_{111}$ can be 1 is if $X_{111}$ is the highest and $X_{110}$ is the second highest.  There are exactly 109! of theses cases: all the permutations of the first 109.